# If null.Equals(null) why do I get a NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, null, nullreferenceexception

I have the following line of code:

```
var selectedDomainID = lkuDomainType.EditValue.Equals(null) 
    ? string.Empty 
    : lkuDomainType.EditValue;
```

Sometimes this generates a `NullReferenceException`. What I don't understand is why. Isn't the whole point of my code to check for `null` and if so assign `string.empty`?  When I check in DEBUG it is stating that `EditValue == null` so what am I missing?

Comment: can't lkuDomkainType be null itself? When you call lkuDomainType.EditValue , it throws the NullReferenceException.

Comment: Because of your title: `a == b` is not the same as `a.Equals(b)`.

Comment: @Stefan: Great point!  Changed to be more accurate for future searchers...Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use `lkuDomainType.EditValue == null`, otherwise you are trying to call an instance method on a null object. But the better option might be `lkuDomainType.EditValue ?? String.Empty`. Also watch out for `lkuDomainType` being null, unless it is a class not an object.

Comment: Thanks, seems pretty obvious in hindsight, definitely a 'duh' moment.  Thanks.

Comment: +2 (unfortunately not possible) for the correct answer and the recommendation to use `??`.

Comment: +1: The null coalescing (or `??`) operator was a great addition to .NET and something I sorely miss when using Java.

Answer (score 16):

When you use `Object.Property` and `Object` is undefined, you are dereferencing a null pointer and that's why you get the exception. Instead, use:

```
var selectedDomainID = lkuDomainType.EditValue == null ? string.Empty : lkuDomainType.EditValue;
```

Comment: I had to upvote this answer a) for the correct answer, b) for using *dereference* in the sentence, and b) for the almost appropriate user name

Comment: Great answer, +1, but SO says that @Yuriy's answer was first.  Thanks though.

Comment: @Refracted Yes it was, by 4 seconds :) I like his/her suggestion of using `??`

Comment: @Refracted Yes, you're right. I've forgot to mention that I upvoted Yuriy's answer, too, for using the `??` operator

Comment: In this case, it's `Object.Property.Method`, and if either `Object` or `Property` are undefined, you'd be dereferencing a null pointer.

Answer (score 5):

If `EditValue` is null then you can't call `Equals`. In this cas you would have to do:

```
var selectedDomainID = lkuDomainType.EditValue == null ? string.Empty : lkuDomainType.EditValue;
```

Or you can simplify it by doing:

```
var selectedDomainID = lkuDomainType.EditValue ?? string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 3):

you are trying to call the Equals method on a null object - do it like this instead:

```
lkuDomainType.EditValue == null
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are using the object before checking if it's null. You are calling the `Equals` method of the object, which fails if the reference is null.

You have to exchange your `lkuDomainType.EditValue.Equals(null)` for `lkuDomainType.EditValue == null`.

Answer (score 2):

EditValue == null.  That means that there is no object there.  You cannot call functions on null objects, even if the function is .Equals().

You're better off just saying "(lkuDomainType.EditValue == null)" in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [String.IsNullOrEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) here.  Like this:

```
var selectedDomainID = String.IsNullOrEmpty(lkuDomainType.EditValue) ? string.Empty : lkuDomainType.EditValue;
```

Equals is a method, you're trying to call a method on a null object which is throwing an exception.

Comment: I don't understand, isn't `String.IsNullOrEmpty` also a *method*?

Comment: It's a static method, it's not a method of the lkuDomainType.EditValue object.

Answer (score 2):

when EditValue is null you cannot call the Equals method on it so the best way to check is to use

```
lkuDomainType.EditValue == null ? string.Empty : lkuDomainType.EditValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

All current answers fail to address a critical point: the difference between calling `Equals` on a `Nullable`  type (which is a `struct`) vs. `class` type.

Calling `Equals` on a `Nullable` typed object whose value is null will not issue an exception, while doing the same on a `class` typed object will.

Consider the following code:

```
int? num = null; // int? is Nullable<int>
String s = null; // String is a class

var equalsNullable = num.Equals(null); // works
var equalsClass = s.Equals(null);      // throws
```

The reason is that `Nullable`'s `HasValue` method is called in such case, see [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8249499/3002584) for more info.

As other people said, the way to go in the OP's case is to use `==` or `??`.

Answer (score 0):

If lkuDomainType.EditValue is null, then "lkuDomainType.EditValue.Equals(someObject)" is the same as coding "null.Equals(someObject)".  Well, obviously "null" doesn't have any members or methods (it wouldn't be null if it did).  That's why you get a NullReferenceException.

Most of the examples from the other posts will work, including String.IsNullOrEmpty, which is a method that returns a boolean value.